# Would you always create a variable for new objects?

Tags: .net

A question I often ask myself, if you need to call one method on an object, is it best practice to use a variable? Thus far I've guessed the answer is Yes - what's your choice, and reasons for it?

With variable:

```
MyObject mo = new MyObject();
mo.MyMethod();
//mo not used again
```

Without variable:

```
new MyObject().MyMethod();
```

I'm particularly interested in .NET, however if there are any danger points in other languages I'd also prefer to be forewarned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you describe it, there is no effective difference between the two alternatives. But if you often need to create an instance of an object, just to call a single method; you should consider if your design is right ? Is it neccessary to have all these short-lived objects ? Remember, that for each object allocation, the garbage collector eventually has to collect the reference.

Answer (score 9):

An alternate way could be using static methods. This way, you can avoid creating a new object.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static int GetSomeInt()
  {
     //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, creating an object just to call a single method can be a code smell for over encapsulation (that said it can be perfectly valid too)

Comment: @Binary Worrier - not if you are making good use of inheritance.

Comment: The particular case that applied today was creating a Repository object to retrieve the users profile on application startup. 
I'm actually in the process of changing our application away from our previous 'static' data access layer to follow the repository pattern.

Answer (score 7):

No, I frequently chain method calls, particularly with LINQ:

```
var query = source.Where(...)
                  .Select(...)
                  .Take(10);
```

Extra variables can be useful if you want to debug the intermediate value, and for *explaining* the intermediate value (via the name) but otherwise, there are no real problems.

Comment: At a risk of questioning Jon Skeet.. 

I think the question is asking if its better to use 

SourceObject source = new SourceObject();
var query = source.Where().Select().Take();

or 

var query = new SourceObject().Where().Select();

- To which I'd say it depends if u plan on using the sourceobject later :)

A commonly written by me thing is 

bool executed = new XXCommand(...).Execute();

but if i wanted to use the Item stored on the command later, I would use 

XXCommand command = new XXCommand();
if (command.Execute())
{
    Item = command.Item;
}

Comment: Well in this example I've assumed the "source" variable already exists... but the point is that there isn't a separate variable for the results of Where, then another one for the results of Select, then another one for the results of Take.

Comment: Tim is correct, I was specifically interested when newing objects. I'll update the Q to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Your two statements are virtually identical at the IL level so do whatever is more readable to you.

Answer (score 1):

There  is a technical difference, albiet a minor one... When using a variable you are telling the compiler to create an extra memory slot on the stack, in the currently running method's stack frame, to hold the reference to (address of) the newly created object (unless compiler optimizes it away)

when you just 'chain' the new object() syntax with the call to it's member method or property, this reference is not stored anywhere, so, (again, unless the compiler optimizes it away) it should be marginally faster.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use variable, it's more readable.

In my case, since you ask, in C++, when allocating a new variable on the heap (with new), I always check for NULL pointer (and in some case check for exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

I would lean toward your "without variable" excerpt as well, especially if the object would not be used again.

- This produces more concise code.
- Since you are performing a single function, a single line is nice.
- However, greater concision may come at the cost of increased complexity.

Ultimately, go with whichever pattern produces the most understandable/maintainable code for you.  As you note, there are pros and cons with each pattern.